# Too many threads are running in multi-threaded step

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a multi-threaded step created with max thread limit 10;

```
private static final int THREAD_NUMBER = 10;

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("batch-thread");
    simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(THREAD_NUMBER);
    return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
}


@Bean
protected Tasklet readHeader() {
    EkuampVorsatzReader ekuampVorsatzReader = new EkuampVorsatzReader();
    return ekuampVorsatzReader;
}

@Bean
public Step stepGetPriceFileHeader(){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("batch-job_price_file-step-get-pricefile-header").tasklet(readHeader()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step stepGetPriceFileData() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("batch-job_price_file-step-get-pricefile-data")
            .<ImportLogEntity, ImportLogEntity>chunk(50)
            .reader(priceFileReader).listener(priceFileReaderListener)
            .writer(priceFileWriter)
            .listener(priceFileStepListener)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(THREAD_NUMBER)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job batchJobPriceFile() {
    Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("batch-job_price_file")
            .start(stepGetPriceFileHeader())
            .next(stepGetPriceFileData())
            .listener(jobExecutionListener)
            .build();
    return job;
}
```

After a 2 million records file processed I can see in log file that are too many threads created even I set the limit to 10 threads.
Ex: INFO [batch-thread35348]
Can you please tell me why? Thank you.

> 2019-07-02T17:02:29,896 8129857 INFO [batch-thread35348] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,147 8130108 INFO [batch-thread35341] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileWriterListener ([]) - PriceFileWriterListener - afterWrite; List size:50
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,191 8130152 INFO [batch-thread35343] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileWriterListener ([]) - PriceFileWriterListener - afterWrite; List size:50
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,219 8130180 INFO [batch-thread35342] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileWriterListener ([]) - PriceFileWriterListener - afterWrite; List size:50
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,340 8130301 INFO [batch-thread35344] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileWriterListener ([]) - PriceFileWriterListener - afterWrite; List size:50
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,504 8130465 INFO [batch-thread35345] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileWriterListener ([]) - PriceFileWriterListener - afterWrite; List size:50
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,513 8130474 INFO [batch-thread35349] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,513 8130474 INFO [batch-thread35350] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,513 8130474 INFO [batch-thread35351] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,513 8130474 INFO [batch-thread35352] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,513 8130474 INFO [batch-thread35354] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,513 8130474 INFO [batch-thread35353] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,513 8130474 INFO [batch-thread35355] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileReaderListener ([]) - PriceFileReaderListener - beforeRead
>   2019-07-02T17:02:30,586 8130547 INFO [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] com.db.wmdl.pricefile.job.batch.listener.PriceFileJobListener ([]) - SpringBatchJob [inbound-id: 56435] [spring-batch-job-execution-id: 21] import completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` does not reuse threads. Here is an excerpt from its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html):

> NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads! Consider a thread-pooling TaskExecutor implementation instead, in particular for executing a large number of short-lived tasks.

In your case, you can use the [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) and set its `maxPoolSize` to 10.

Comment: Thank you a lot. A tried with ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and the results are:

SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor -- > 10 sec/ 1000 lines;
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  -->  28 sec/ 1000 lines.

So the SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is much better in terms of time. The time is very important to me.

If I keep SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is a good approach or resource consuming?

Comment: The performance comparison between task executors is another story. Please accept the answer if it answers your question (and it does IMO). To answer your second question: No, `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor ` is not efficient in terms of resources consumption as it will create a thread for each task. If you correctly configure the thread pool based one, you should also get good performance.